# JS: cache string array at client for entire session

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, session, caching

I have a drop-down list that shows all cities in a country - some few thousand strings.

It's a plain JS array, and I'd like to store it in the user's cache for the entire session, instead of having his browser download it on each request.

Just for the reference I'm using ASP.NET MVC, not that I think it matters. jQuery is also one of the libs I'm using.

I prefer to use built-in ways over adding new libraries to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sessionStorage`:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('cities', JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]))
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cities')) // [1, 2, 3]
```

> data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends.
>   A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives
>   over page reloads and restores.

more information about [localStorage and sessionStorage](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html)

Comment: What other lengths are there besides session? Any longer-term caching available?

Comment: localStorage hold a data until deleted by user (delete cache), sessionStorage until the browser is closed

Comment: Found the answer in the link you provided: `localStorage`.

Comment: you got me ahead with 7 seconds... Thanks